# Incorrect time delta in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert UTC time to LST

```py
d['dtime [LST]'] = d['dtime_UTC'] - datetime.timedelta(hours=8)
```

UTC is in mm/dd/yyyy h:m format here
for this time in UTC 01-01-2023 23:55 I am getting LST as 01-01-2023 15:55 (which is correct)
but for this time in UTC 01-02-2023 00:02 I am getting LST as 31-01-2023 16:02. (incorrect)

I know that it is taking incorrect format for timedelta. 2nd of Jan is taken as 1st of Feb and minus 8 hours is 31st of Jan for LST. How to get the correct format in LST so that timedelta works properly?

Comment: So it's not an incorrect time delta, it's not having the proper date-month format. The question needs a rephrasing.

Comment: At some point you would have to parse the date strings to proper datetime values, for instance using `pd.to_datetime`. Make sure you are using the correct format specifier there. PS: I would recommend the builtin functionality to set (tz_localize) and convert (tz_convert) timezones in pandas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You first parse the date column using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```py
from datetime import timedelta

d['dtime_UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(d['dtime_UTC'], format='%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')
d['dtime [LST]'] = d['dtime_UTC'] - timedelta(hours=8)
```